# UiTableView not showing, GetCell not being called

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I have the following code set up:

```
        TableView = new UITableView();
        TableView.Source = new DataSource();

        m_MainScroll.Add(view); // scrollview area
        TableView.ReloadData ();
```

DataSource is simple:

```
    class DataSource : UITableViewSource {
        public DataSource ()
        {
        }

        public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return 10;
        }

        // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return new UITableViewCell();
        }
    }
```

Basically GetCell is never called and I never see the table show up anyway.

Any ideas why?

edit:

Some more potentially relevant code:

(in ViewDidLoad):

```
        m_MainScroll = new UIScrollView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 372));
        m_MainScroll.ContentSize = new SizeF(300, ScrollerHeight);
        m_MainScroll.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
        m_MainScroll.DraggingStarted += DragStarted;

        AddComponent(m_MainScroll);


        UIToolbar bar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 372, 320, 44));
        View.Add(bar);
        UIBarButtonItem barBut = new UIBarButtonItem();
        barBut.Style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered;
        barBut.Title = "Next";
        NextButton = barBut;

        UIBarButtonItem flexer = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);

        UIBarButtonItem []items = new UIBarButtonItem[2];
        items[0] = flexer;
        items[1] = barBut;
        bar.Items = items;

        AddComponent(bar);


    public void AddComponent(UIView view)
    {
        m_Components.Add(view);
        View.Add(view);
    }
```

Where m_Components is just a list of UIView and is really only used to defocus controls which have the keyboard on.

Comment: I think we'll need a bit of extra code regarding the initialization and how/where TableView is used. Also, not an answern but I suggest you to look at MonoTouch.Dialog to be far more productive when dealing with tables https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Comment: the above comment is mostly about `m_MainScroll.Add(view);` and the `view`, `m_MainScroll` and `TableView` relationship in your code.

Comment: oh right, I added the missing pieces :)